# React setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Недавно начал практиковать React, однако столкнулся с проблемой удаления записей из списка.

**Быть точнее: есть список пользователей, что рендерится на сайте; у каждого блока из этого списка есть опция удаления:**

**Промис удаления:**

```
const delUserPromise = (id) =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve(this.state.users.filter((e) => e.id !== id));
  });
```

**Функция вызова промиса удаления:**

```
delUser = (id) => {
  this.delUserPromise(id).then((arr) => {
    this.setState({ users: arr }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.users);
    });
  });
};
```

---

Однако данная опция удаления не работает: возвращается правильный массив пользователей, который должен отобразится на сайте и меняется state, но **ничего на сайте не происходит**. *(На функциях, использующих state, выполнен bind в constructor'e)*

Пытался искать что-то связанное с этой темой, но там была проблема в неправильном массиве и т.п., но ответа на свой вопрос так и не нашел. Прошу помощи.

---

[image: Изначальный вид списка пользователей до удаления]

*Изначальный вид списка пользователей до удаления*

[image: Массив пользователей после нажатия удаления]

*Массив пользователей после нажатия удаления (console)*

[image: Вид списка после удаления]

*Вид списка после удаления*

**Users class render func:**

```
render = () => {
  if (this.users.length > 0) {
    return (
      <div>
        {" "}
        {this.users.map((el) => (
          <User delUser={this.props.onDel} key={el.id} user={el} />
        ))}{" "}
      </div>
    );
  } else
    return (
      <div className="user">
        {" "}
        <h3>Пользователей нет</h3>{" "}
      </div>
    );
};
```

**User class render func:**

```
render = () => (
  <div className="user">
    {" "}
    <AiFillCloseCircle
      id="close-icon"
      onClick={() => this.props.delUser(this.user.id)}
    />{" "}
    <MdModeEditOutline id="edit-icon" />{" "}
    <h3>
      {this.user.name} ({this.user.age})
    </h3>{" "}
    <p>Working as a {this.user.job}</p>{" "}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Как вы рендерите данный список?

Comment: @SwaD добавил функции рендера Users и User

Comment: `<div> {this.users.map` а нужно `<div> {this.state.users.map`

Comment: users определено в классе как this.props.users(передается из app.js)

Comment: @Yami но он же не меняется. Меняется стейт. У вас выходит, что меняете стейт, а выводите неизмененный список, пришедший из props

Comment: в общем у вас из поста не понятно. В каком компоненте находится стейт с юзерами? В каком компоненте выполняются промисы по удалению? Вы можете исправить вопрос с кодом всех участвующих компонентов, а не кусками?

Comment: Если у вас компоненты на классах, то SO позволяет без проблем все вывести

Comment: @DmitryKozlov, да и вправду передавалось из users неправильно.